# Why is gremlin-server not returning an edge by it's ID?

Tags: java, gremlin, gremlin-server

I'm using gremlin-server 3.4.11 and connecting to it with java tinkerpop gremlin-driver.

`g.E()` returns all the edges:

```
[
  {
    "id": 18,
    "label": "RELATED",
    "type": "edge",
    "inVLabel": "GREMLIN2",
    "outVLabel": "GREMLIN1",
    "inV": 16,
    "outV": 14
  }
]
```

but `g.E(18)` OR `g.E().hasId(18)` returns empty list:

```
[]
```

Why is that? I would assume, that the corresponding edge would be returned, but it is not. What am I missing here?

*Note*: I tried to create an edge with `g.V(14).addE('RELATED').property('id', 'someId').to(g.V(16))`.. this is then found with `g.E().has('id', 'someId')`, BUT it is not the ID of the edge, merely property named 'id'. `hasId()` step also returns empty list.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using TinkerGraph? Is yes, the IDs are stored as `long` internally.

Please try `g.E(18L)`

Comment: you are correct, it is working with "18L", thank you! Would you happen to know why this works with vertices? g.V('14'), g.V(14), g.V().hasId(14), g.V().hasId('14') does return Vertex

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different Graphs; If you are using Tinker Graph then you have to use: the format L. This is because the ID value is stored as a long internally for the tinkerPop Graph. Some use case examples are: g.V(1L) this will return a vertex with an ID of 1. Likewise, the ID's for edges are stored as longs too; g.E(2L) returns the edge with an ID of 2